# How can I use the deprecated YouTube Data API to get video comments?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have an application where we would like to display YouTube video comments. In the YouTube API 2 there was support for retrieving video comments - this functionality is no longer available in API 3.

As stated in the docs:

> You can continue using the v2 API for comments and uploading video
>   captions for now, and we'll be adding this functionality into the v3
>   API soon. While we don’t have specific dates yet, we will release that
>   functionality so that developers have as much time as possible to
>   migrate to v3.
>
> ...there
>   will not be 100% feature parity between the v2 and v3 APIs. Please see
>   the v3 API documentation for more details as to what functionality is
>   supported in v3.

As I understand it, you need to register your app through the Google Developer console for the API you wish to use first, and there is no longer an option to add YouTube API 2. I tried sending a request to the old endpoint

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VideoIdHere/comments
```

but got the following response

> `No longer available`

Is there a way I can still use the API 2 to retrieve video comments? How can I accomplish this?

**Edit:**

YouTube video comments are now available at the following endpoint

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads
```

See the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, API v2 is completely deprecated and no longer available. You will need to use API v3.

Example call: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2C+replies&maxResults=50&videoId=VIDEO_ID&order=time&textFormat=plainText&key=API_KEY

Comment: I use API v3 to import youtube video comments.